# Magento v2.1.7 admin login error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin

Can’t login into the admin panel of Magento2.also try command in case the account is locked is?

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock ADMINUSERNAME
```

And manually edit password in the `admin_user` table in the database.
But it seems not fixed it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't change the password from the `admin_user` table.

You must run below command for enabling the user. You must change **username** with your username (Ex.: admin).

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock username
```

Comment: He already tried this solution. He mentioned above command in his question

Comment: I saw, but you change the password in the admin_user table and is not ok.

Comment: You can add a new user from terminal command and after change password your old account from admin panel.

Comment: @St3phan, I already run above command which you have mentioned but getting same error.

Comment: Did you try to create a new user from the terminal?

Comment: Yes, @St3phan .I also tried create new user.Finally it resolve issue on some changes in file path                                                                                                                                      \vendor\zendframework\zend-crypt\src\Utils.php   to replace code with       if (function_exists('hash_equals')) { return hash_equals($expected, $actual); }
To
if (function_exists('hash_equals')) { return true; }

Comment: Very strange CORE